# require_once not working properly

Tags: php, cron, openshift

I'm using openshift host to develop my custom application.
In this folder:

```
 /var/lib/openshift/000000000000000000000000/app-root/runtime/repo/php/script.php
```

I've placed my php file, each file have a require_once for include some functions. The problem's that the require_once doesn't see any files in the same folder!
I've so create this script:

```
if(file_exists("tool.php")==TRUE)
{
    file_put_contents(getenv('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR').'php/debug.txt', 'exists', FILE_APPEND); 
}
else
{
file_put_contents(getenv('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR').'php/debug.txt', "not found", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

but in the `debug.txt` file I get ever

> not found

In my script.php I've this directory: `require_once("tool.php");` 
What I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the file `tool.php` located in the same directory as the `script` running that code?

Comment: tool.php is in the same directory and script run the code because I receive teh debug.txt file and I can read the content

Comment: Use git to deploy your code changes. It sounds like you're just live editing files in the repo directory. In the meantime, try re-starting your gear and see if that helps.